# Send List<T> as an optional parameter in the post body in ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

I had this model which was taking optional params for a post request body:

```
 public class ReportFilterModel
{

    public int? ReportStatusId { get; set; }
    public Guid? AreaID { get; set; }
}
```

This would do a search in DB according to the filters given by user:

```
 var report = _context.tbl_Reports.AsQueryable();

                if (model.ReportStatusId.IsNotNull())
                    report = report.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.ReportStatusId == (StatusEnum)model.ReportStatusId.Value);

                if (model.Area.IsNotNull())
                    report = report.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.Area.Id == model.AreaId);
```

And then it'd finally return this:

```
 finalReports = await report
                    .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                    .Select(x => new ReportsWithFiltersModel
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,

                        Area = Id,
                        UserId = x.UserId,
                        ReportStatus = x.ReportStatusId.GetEnumDescription(),

                    }).ToListAsync();
```

All this working absolutely fine, but now I want to give a list of optional params like this:

```
public class ReportFilterModel
{

    public List<int>? ReportStatusId { get; set; }
    public List<Guid>? AreaID { get; set; }
}
```

This is giving an exception

```
'List<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'List<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two concepts [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) and [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) (added in C# 8.0). Nullabale value types marked with `?` are basically shortcut for [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1) and they have [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value?view=netcore-3.1) property. `List<T>` (in your case `List<int>` and `List<Guid>`) is reference type and it does not have `Value` property and marking it with `?` makes compiler aware that this property can contain `null` reference and make it able to enforce rules to ensure that you've correctly checked this property for a null reference. So in the nutshell your `List<int>? ReportStatusId` and `List<Guid>? AreaID` already "optional" and `?` makes compiler aware of that.

*Hot to fix that?*

Change

```
 if (model.ReportStatusId.IsNotNull())
     report = report.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.ReportStatusId == (StatusEnum)model.ReportStatusId.Value);
```

to

```
if (model.ReportStatusId.IsNotNull() && model.ReportStatusId.Any())
     var statuses = model.ReportStatusId.Cast<StatusEnum>().ToList();
     report = report.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && statuses.Contains(x.ReportStatusId));
```

Answer (score 1):

? Does not stand for optional. It means Nullable where T is value type (It applies to value types and makes them nullable).

Reference types, such as Lists are already nullable.

```
List<int> x = null; //valid version of what you are trying to achieve with List<int>?

int? or Nullable<int> //valid
List<int?> x or List<Nullable<int>> ; //valid
```

Comment: you forgot about C#8 feature [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)